# Consuming a Spring Shutdown Endpoint

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, http

My application has a SpringBoot process running as a separate service. When this process is done listening, I want to shut it down gracefully. In order to achieve this, I implemented the following endpoint which I found [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-shutdown#1-close-the-current-application-context).

```
@RestController
public class ShutdownController implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private ApplicationContext context;

    @PostMapping("/shutdown")
    public void shutdownContext() {
        ((ConfigurableApplicationContext) context).close();
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext ctx) throws BeansException {
        this.context = ctx;

    }
}
```

The problem comes when I try to send a request to the endpoint from my app. This is the code I'm running:

```
new RestTemplate().postForLocation(shutdownUri, null);
```

Throws:

> org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on
>   POST request for "http://localhost:8083/shutdown": Unexpected end of
>   file from server; nested exception is java.net.SocketException:
>   Unexpected end of file from server

I believe the reason behind this exception is that Spring shuts down and remains unable to send a proper response, please correct me if I'm wrong.
I know I could catch this exception and Spring would shut down properly, but I would like to know if there is a cleaner way to consume the endpoint.

Comment: Could you elaborate your question which method did you try with code examples?

Comment: @kamaci I'm sorry I didn't get your question. The method I tried is the one shown in the snippet of the original post.

Comment: I mean could you provide the endpoint implementation.

Comment: @kamaci done :)

Comment: I have provided an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Boot application cannot respond to request since it has been shutdown. So, you can create a service which handles shutdown process as async, you can wait for the client to inform that application has received shutdown request successfully and then shutdown the application.

Create a service class:

```
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Async;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class ShutdownService implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private ApplicationContext context;

    @Async
    public void shutDown() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5_000);
            ((ConfigurableApplicationContext) context).close();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            //
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext ctx) throws BeansException {
        this.context = ctx;
    }
}
```

To make it work, mark your application class as:

```
@EnableAsync
```

You can also tune `Executor` settings aligned with your needs.

Create your controller as follows:

```
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class ShutdownController {

    private final ShutdownService shutdownService;

    public ShutdownController(ShutdownService shutdownService) {
        this.shutdownService = shutdownService;
    }

    @PostMapping("/shutdown")
    public ResponseEntity<String> shutdownContext() {
        shutdownService.shutDown();
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body("Shutdown request is successfully received.");
    }
}
```

You may wan to double check that whether something wrong happened while shutdown process.

Comment: Did it work or do you need any other clarifications?